# Getting variable from callback method without using static keyword in java

Tags: java

Class MyApplication observes another class and is itself observed.  The problem is that the updates to the booleans replyOne and replyTwo by the "update" method are not visible to the "run" method.   I wish to have multiple copies of the MyApplication class running and so do not want to use the static keyword. Is there any way having the run method see the changes to the booleans without using the static keyword to modify the booleans?

The observed and the MyApplication class are launched by a another class as follows:

```
final ServerOne firstServer = new ServerOne();
    MyApplication appOne = new MyApplication();

    // subscribe the observers to the observed - eberybody watches each other
    firstServer.addObserver(appOne);
    appOne.addObserver(firstServer);

    // start the  threads 
    Thread firstServerThread = new Thread(firstServer,"firstServer");
    firstServerThread.start();
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(appOne, "appOne");
    thread3.start();
```

The code for the MyApplication class is as follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends Observable implements Observer, Runnable {

    private String resp, response;
    private long timeTaken;
    private boolean replyOne,replyTwo;


    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object arg) {

        timeTaken = (System.nanoTime() - ((Long) arg).longValue()) / 1000;

        if (observable instanceof ServerOne) {
            //process ObservableCLass1 update here

            System.out.println("App Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " received update from serverOne in " + timeTaken + " microSecs");
            this.replyOne = true;
        } else if (observable instanceof ServerTwo) {

            System.out.println("App Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " received update from serverTwo in " + timeTaken + " microSecs");
            this.replyTwo = true;
        }

        timeTaken = ((Long) arg).longValue();
        setChanged();

        notifyObservers(timeTaken);
        clearChanged();

    }

    public void run() {

        this.replyOne = false;
        this.replyTwo = false;

        while (!this.replyOne || !this.replyTwo) {
            // wait until the observer has set both the reply flags

            if (this.replyOne) {
                System.out.println("Reply one True ");
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(new String("app Calling after update from serverOne "));
                this.replyOne = false;
            }

            if (this.replyTwo) {
                System.out.println("Reply two True ");
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers(new String("app Calling after update from serverTwo "));
                this.replyTwo = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If the changes are not visible it's because you have two different instances of the object.

Comment: Thanks.  Is this because the update method that is called by the observed class creates a new instance of MyApplication?

Comment: How do you expect to set a value in one instance of an object and have that value miraculously appear in another instance of the object?  It's like expecting the milk your neighbor brought home and put into his fridge to miraculously appear in yours.

Comment: @HotLicks Where am I creating the second instance of the class MyApplication?  I create one instance, appOne, set it as the observer of the firstServer class and then call the run method of the appOne instance.   Any constructive ideas of how to pass data from the update method to the run method?

Comment: Your comments are unclear.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm sorry you were unable to understand them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues. First, look at your `run` method:

```
this.replyOne = false;
this.replyTwo = false;

while (!this.replyOne && this.replyTwo) {
```

You first set both variable to `false` then enter a loop if `replyTwo` is `true` which is very unlikely to ever happen. Most probably, you meant: `while (!this.replyOne && !this.replyTwo)`.

But the entire construct looks suspicious. It’s clear that the waiting code which is missing here shall be in a loop waiting for it least one flag to become `true` but why are the notifications also inside the loop? Under which condition shall the `run` method wait again and when should it exit?

Maybe you have oversimplified. The intended code might be rather like this:

```
this.replyOne = false;
this.replyTwo = false;

while(!endCondition) {

    while (!this.replyOne && !this.replyTwo) {
        // wait until the observer has set both the reply flags
    }
    if (this.replyOne) {
        System.out.println("Reply one True ");
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(new String("app Calling after update from serverOne "));
        this.replyOne = false;
    }

    if (this.replyTwo) {
        System.out.println("Reply two True ");
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(new String("app Calling after update from serverTwo "));
        this.replyTwo = false;
    }
}
```

I assume that you put a correct thread-safe construct at the place where the comment says “wait until the observer has set both the reply flags”. Otherwise there is no memory visibility guaranty, in other words, this loop might run infinitely, even if another thread modified one of these variables.

Comment: Thanks I copied the code (to simplifiy it) and I missed it the "!".  The issue I have is that variable replyOne is never updated in the run method by the code in the update method.

Comment: It’s not just the `!`, it’s that your entire loop ends when `replyOne` is `true`. You need a construct like the two nested loops in my example *and* you need a thread-safe waiting construct. As long as you simplify it away in your code sample, nobody can say, what’s wrong with it (besides assuming that it’s simply not there).

Comment: I changed to && to || so the loop will execute until both replyOne and replyTwo are true.  These variables are private to this class and there will only be one instance of this class per thread.   They are only updated by the update method of this class.   Or am I missing something.  Is the update method executed in the thread of the Observed class?

Comment: If you are still using the loop the way you have written in the question, it still makes no sense. You want the body of the loop executed if the flags are `true`, that’s the point of your `if` statements. So as long as you have your `if` statements in a loop that is told to *end* once the flags became `true` it is counteracting your intents. But if you have “one instance of this class per thread” they will wait forever anyway, how should a variable dedicated to a single thread ever change here? And the update method is executed in the thread which invokes the update method, of course.

Comment: Thank you Holger.  This solves it.  The problem I have is that as you say the update method is invoked in the thread that invokes the update and so the flags will never change.  I need to find a way to get the first thread to update a variable in the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

`notifyObservers` with an extra event class object containing `replyOne` and `replyTwo` would be the classical way.

```
public class ReplyEvent {
    public boolean replyOne;
    ...
}


ReplyEvent evt = new ReplyEvent();
evt.message = "...";
evt.replyOne = replyOne;
...
notifyObservers(evt);
```